# Get IDs of all unchecked checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

My main goal is to post "0" when a checkbox is unchecked. I have come across a technique where I need to put a hidden field that has the same name as with my checkbox. Once a checkbox is checked, the hidden field is disabled. It works wonder for me, however, the code seems to be so long and I wanted to look a way to shorten this up.

HTML:

```
<div id="subscriptionForm">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkLeft" name="checkLeft1" id="checkLeft1" />
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="checkLeft1" id="checkLeft1Hidden" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkLeft" name="checkLeft2" id="checkLeft2"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="checkLeft2" id="checkLeft2Hidden" />

  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkRight" name="checkRight1" id="checkRight1"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="checkRight1" id="checkRight1Hidden" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkRight" name="checkRight2" id="checkRight2"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="checkRight2" id="checkRigh21Hidden" />
</div>
```

Script:

```
function disableHidden() {
  if ($("#checkLeft1").is(":checked")) {
    $("#check1Hidden").attr("disabled", true);
  }
  if ($("#checkLeft2").is(":checked")) {
    $("#check2Hidden").attr("disabled", true);
  }
  if ($("#checkRight1").is(":checked")) {
    $("#trAsiaEuropeHidden").attr("disabled", true);
  }
  if ($("#checkRight2").is(":checked")) {
    $("#trAsiaNamHidden").attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

I had to put different classes on left and right so as to follow the desired layout.

Do you have some suggestion on this?
Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve by disabling `hidden-input`..

Comment: The double input field workaround, is usually used to avoid needing to use Javascript, when the script receiving the form data correctly overwrites the existing input value (e.g. PHP), instead of treating them as an array (e.g. Node Express). Is there any requirement for one or the other? If you're allowed to use Javascript, you could create some code to just change the values of the unchecked input fields, before they're submitted.

Comment: May be... `$('#subscriptionForm :checkbox').on('change',function(){ $(this).next(':hidden').prop('disabled', this.checked) }).change();`

Comment: Of what I understand, radio button seems more appropriate maybe ?

Comment: its posting to Eloqua, so if I do not disable the hidden fields, the value posted can look like this (0, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the stuff you have in your code is a bit overkill. Depending on the place which is receiving the data (if PHP), you should be able to move the hidden fields to above their associated checkboxes, then remove the Javascript completely.

```
<div id="subscriptionForm">
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="checkLeft1" id="checkLeft1Hidden" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkLeft" name="checkLeft1" id="checkLeft1" />
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="checkLeft2" id="checkLeft2Hidden" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkLeft" name="checkLeft2" id="checkLeft2"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="checkRight1" id="checkRight1Hidden" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkRight" name="checkRight1" id="checkRight1"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="checkRight2" id="checkRigh21Hidden" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkRight" name="checkRight2" id="checkRight2"/>
</div>
```

If, however, you'd rather some Javascript, and cleaner HTML, then you could just insert some hidden fields, like:

```
function zeroOutUncheckedFields() {
  $('#subscriptionForm input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).after('<input type="hidden" name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '" value="0">')
    }
  });
}
```

and your HTML can just be:

```
<div id="subscriptionForm">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkLeft" name="checkLeft1" id="checkLeft1" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkLeft" name="checkLeft2" id="checkLeft2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkRight" name="checkRight1" id="checkRight1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkRight" name="checkRight2" id="checkRight2"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a consistent naming pattern for your checkbox/hidden fields, or you have a guaranteed consistent placement of a hidden field after your checkboxes, you wouldn't be able to programmatically do it.

Do your checkboxes have to be named that way? Are you going to have hidden fields placed immediately after checkboxes? The reason I ask is because of the trAsia... ids you've listed in your sample script.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "disable" the hidden input if the checkbox preceding it is checked then you could do something like this:

```
   $('#subscriptionForm').find('[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        $(this).next('[type="hidden"]').attr('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
   }).change();
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zka3m8a1/3/**

Answer (score 0):

Do you Mean : https://jsfiddle.net/aonk3730/

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $(this).next("input[type='hidden']").attr("disabled", true);
  }else{
    $(this).next("input[type='hidden']").attr("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

HTML

```
<div id="subscriptionForm">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkLeft" name="checkLeft1" id="checkLeft1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkLeft" name="checkLeft2" id="checkLeft2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkRight" name="checkRight1" id="checkRight1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkRight" name="checkRight2" id="checkRight2"/>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  console.log($(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked'))
$(this).next('input[type="hidden"]').attr('disabled','disabled')
else
$(this).next('input[type="hidden"]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/c8ue0d3d/6/